# How can I update Windows Server 2019 from 1809 to 1903?

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2019

I can not update my Windows Server Standard 2019 from 1809 to 1903. Here is what I have so far:

- the system is installed from scratch and using the distribution kit obtained from the Microsoft website
- System activated
- Internet access direct and without proxy (this is confirmed by the output of the netsh winhttp show proxy command)
- installed current SSU 4512577
- by clicking to check for updates it shows that the system is up to date, but build 1809

How can I update the system or get the distribution kit with 1903?

Comment: Did you ever got to the bottom of this?
Did you try messing around with usoclient ?

Answer (score -3):

You can download the update as an ISO using the Media Creation Tool or install it using the Windows 10 Update Assistant. Both tools are available for free from Microsoft’s website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Fore more info: [Petri](https://www.petri.com/windows-10-may-2019-update-and-windows-server-version-1903-available-for-download)